# TextView не реагирует на нажатие

Tags: android

Пытаюсь сделать кликабельным TextView

```
privacy = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.privacy);
String textWithLink = "<a href=\"https://www.google.ru\">Политика конфиденциальности</a>";
privacy.setText(Html.fromHtml(textWithLink, null, null));
privacy.setLinksClickable(true);
privacy.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Сам TextView такой

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/privacy"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:autoLink="web"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="@string/privacy"
android:textColor="?attr/colorAccent"
android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />
```

Подскажите пожалуйста почему не реагирует на нажатие?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Только что с такой проблемой столкнулся - всё дело в конфликте с `android:autoLink="web"` - просто уберите это и всё заработает.

Comment: Заработало. Спасибо.