# Как включить ссылки в TextView?

Tags: android, android-textview

Всем привет, есть `TextView`, текст ставится с помощью `Html.fromHtml`. Проблема в том, что ссылки могут быть как и в HTML тегах, так и просто текстом:

```
<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
http://google.com
```

Включаю ссылки так:

```
textView.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
```

Ссылки включаются только для первого варианта (в HTML теге). Если использовать `Linkify` то работает только второй вариантом, если использовать их вместе, то что-то одно.

**Как включить ссылки и в HTML и просто текстом?**

Comment: Попробуйте тут посмотреть:

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/773740/17609

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, нет,это вообще не то

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Html` нацелен на обработку тегов и просто url-адреса в тексте не ищет. Но соль в том, что `Linkify` удаляет все существующие `URLSpan'ы`, а потом ищет в оставшемся тексте адреса по заданным паттернам.
Варианты навскидку:

- обработать текст заранее (обернуть url тегами)
- обработать текст после `Html.fromHtml` спанами самому без `Linkify`
- скопировать спаны из текста, обработанного `Html.fromHtml`
  после обработки `Linkify`:

  ```
  TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);
  Spanned fromHtml = Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"http://google.com\">Google</a><br>" +
          "http://google.com");
  SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(fromHtml);
  Linkify.addLinks(builder, Linkify.ALL);
  TextUtils.copySpansFrom(fromHtml, 0, fromHtml.length(), URLSpan.class, builder, 0);
  tv.setText(builder);
  ```

Comment: спасибо за помощь. попытаюсь решить эту проблему)

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то это будет примерно так, в  нужно указать параметры

```
android:autoLink="web"
android:linksClickable="true"
```

Comment: так работает только со ссылками текстом. HTML ссылки не работают