# Android textView не открывается ссылка

Tags: android

Имеется элемент

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/top_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/self_top_title"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:linksClickable="true"/>
```

Я добавил текст в String Pool

```
<string name="self_top_title">Сделайте 3 шага, чтобы выводить заработанные средства на баланс на банковскую карту!\n\n1. Зарегистрируйтесь в качестве \'Самозанятого\' на <a href="https://lknpd.nalog.ru">сайте</a> или в <a href="https://npd.nalog.ru">приложении \'Мой налог\'</a>; \n2. Заполните ниже: <b>свой ИНН, БИК банка и расчетный счет</b> для получения оплаты; \n3. Скачайте договор и загрузите заполненный договор. \nЭти пункты требуется выполнить только <b>один раз</b>.</string>
```

Ссылки стали отображаться в тексте, но при клике на них ничего не происходит.

Я вроде и autoLink указал у TextView

Comment: ClickableSpan отличная штука

Comment: А не надо в коде еще вот это: `tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja нет.\, не работает

Comment: Покажите код - как настраиваете `TextView` на работу со ссылками, получаете текст из ресурсов и вставляете в `TextView`. Кстати `android:autoLink="web"` работает с просто адресами в тексте (`site.com`), но гиперссылки (`<a href="...`) при этом ломаются. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/773781/11515

Answer (score 3):

Удалил все гиперссылки из `R.string`
И по индексу добавил. Можно конечно получить индекс по поиску слова в фразе, но я прям захардкордил.

```
val tv = view.findViewById(R.id.top_title) as TextView
val span: Spannable = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(tv.text)
span.setSpan(object : ClickableSpan() {
    override fun onClick(p0: View) {
        val url = "https://lknpd.nalog.ru/"
        val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        i.data = Uri.parse(url)
        startActivity(i)
    }
}, 136, 141, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

span.setSpan(object : ClickableSpan() {

    override fun onClick(p0: View) {
            val url = "https://npd.nalog.ru/app/"
            val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            i.data = Uri.parse(url)
            startActivity(i)
    }
},148, 173, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

tv.text = span

tv.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
```